# java programs about checking non numeric numbers

Tags: java, while-loop, numbers, numeric

Basically if I put non numeric number it should show like since I put non-numeric number try again with numeric number. I know I'm supposed to use `isDigit` but I don't know where to put it or how to use it properly. 
When I say non-numeric number, it could be English alphabet or anything other than integer number.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{    
    int again = 1;
    while (again == 1)                          
    {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner( System.in );

        double average = 0;
        int total = 0;

        System.out.println( "Enter your digits to calculate average and total digits. ");
        String score = scan.nextLine();


        total = Summation(score);
        average = (double)total / score.length();

        System.out.print ("TOTAL : " + total + "\n");
        System.out.print ("AVERAGE : " + average + "\n");

       System.out.println( "Play again? Press 1 to play ");
       again = scan.nextInt( );
    }
    System.out.println( "Bye~~ ");
}

private static int Summation(String score)
{   

    char[] charArr = score.toCharArray();
    int[] intArr = new int[score.length()];
    int total = 0;
    int j = 0;

    for (int i = charArr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        System.out.println(charArr[i]); // Display the digits in a reversed order
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < charArr.length; i++)
    {
        // Add every individual digit to find the sum
        intArr[i] = Character.getNumericValue(charArr[i]);
        // Converting to intArray from charArray
        total = intArr[i] + total;
    }

    return total; // Return the total number
}
```

Comment: I think by non-numeric number, you may mean something that is not an integer type. Also, when you say you're supposed to use isDigit, do you mean you're supposed to create a method that verifies whether or not a variable is an integer or not?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regular expression to check that the `String` is only digits. Something like

```
private static boolean isNumber(String score) {
    return score.matches("^\\d+$");
}
```

which tests that the `String` begins and ends with digits.

Alternatively, you could write the same function by testing that a `String` contains a non-digit with the `\D` pattern like

```
private static boolean isNumber(String score) {
    return !score.matches("\\D");
}
```

These and other character classes are documented in the [`Pattern` Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Comment: thanks for the advise but is there any other way than creating a new method ?? cause i'm not allowed to have more than one method.

Comment: Test the `String` directly then... as I did in the method. `if (score.matches("^\\d+$")) { /**/ }`

Comment: if (charArr[j].matches( what do i need to put in here again? sorry i'm really beginner)

Comment: This tests if the entire `String` matches a given pattern. Also, `total += (1+i) * intArr[i];`

Comment: @woobinjoo Java `char` is an integral type ([JLS-4.2.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.1)) and I would prefer [`Character.digit(char, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#digit%28char,%20int%29).

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't have spaces in between your input you can use Integer.parseint inside try and in catch you can display message "try again with numeric input " and then continue the loop in catch.
There was a little problem with scanner please see the code.

```
/* package whatever; // don't place package name! */

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    public static Scanner scan = new Scanner( System.in ); //problem fixed
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
         int again=1;
    while (again ==1)                           
    {



        double average = 0;
        int total = 0;

        System.out.println( "Enter your digits to calculate average and total digits. ");
        String score = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println(score);
        try
        {
            Integer.parseInt(score);
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Try with numeric number");

            continue;
        }
        total = Summation(score);
        average = (double)total/score.length();

        System.out.print ("TOTAL : " + total +"\n");
        System.out.print ("AVERAGE : " + average + "\n");

       System.out.println( "Play again? Press 1 to play ");
       again = scan.nextInt( );
    }
    System.out.println( "Bye~~ ");
}   
private static int Summation(String score)
{
 char[] charArr = score.toCharArray();
    int[] intArr= new int[score.length()];
    int total=0;
    int j=0;




    for (int i=charArr.length-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        System.out.println(charArr[i]);                                     // Display the digits in a reversed order
    }

    for (int i=0; i<charArr.length;i++)
    {                                                                       // Add every individual digit to find the sum
        intArr[i] = Character.getNumericValue(charArr[i]);                  // Converting to intArray from charArray
        total = intArr[i] + total;
    }




    return total;                                                           // Return the total number
}

}
```

Comment: i tried but even if I type non numeric numbers still program still calculates total and average with non numeric numbers surprisingly

Comment: there was a problem with scanner see the fix in code.

Comment: but every time i put integers "try with numeric number" keeps showing even though there's no problem with integers. what about switch and break would that work? thank you for your assistance lol...

Comment: whats you input and whats your expected output??
i checked like this its seemed to work.
http://ideone.com/1MwfU7

Comment: it's because of 1 to replay the game. since 1 is an integer (numeric number) it runs it automatically how do i change,,  i was thinking about changing 1 to string or char but it's kind of hard

Comment: TOTAL : 5
AVERAGE : 1.6666666666666667
Play again? Press 1 to play 
Enter your digits to calculate average and total digits. 

Try with numeric number
Enter your digits to calculate average and total digits.

Comment: after i put 1 to play again  this sentence "try with numeric number" displays automatically

Comment: actually scan.nextInt() will not consume newline character so you have to put scan.nextLine() just after this line of code "again = scan.nextInt( );" and this will resolve your issue.